# How to get the last five messages in Paho?

Tags: javascript, html, web, mqtt, paho

I use Paho to create Javascript MQTT Web Application. 
The client receives just the last message which is sent to it recently, but I need the last five messages everytime I open/refresh the web page.
Is there any solution for this purpose?

Comment: MQTT is not made to send the latest message. The only option is to activate the retained message on your broker. It means that when you connect to it via the client and subscribe to the topic, it will automatically send the retained message. MQTT is not made to send historical data. An option would be to add a script that will subscribe to a topic and save the latest 5 messages. Compact those message in one big message and set it as retained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MQTT doesn't work this way.

There are a number of factors that need to be covered here.

1. **Retained messages**. It sounds like the messages you are receiving have the retained bit in the headers set. This means that the broker will hang on to the last message with that bit set on any topic it is published on, then when a client subscribes to that topic it will always deliver that last message to the client before any new messages arrive. This is just a single message there is no way to have more.
2. **Message queueing**. If a client subscribes to a topic at greater than QOS 0 and then disconnects. When it reconnects as long as the clean_session flag is set to false the and the client resubscribes to the same topic then then the broker will deliver any messages that were sent to the topic while the client was offline. Again this will be all missed messages not just the last 5.

As @Weedoze mentioned in their comment, one possible solution is to have another client subscribe to the same topic and every time a message is published use this to update a single message holding the last 5 messages, this would need to then be published to a separate topic with the retained bit set to true. The client could then subscribe to the "history" topic and the "live" topic.